# Is there only one distribution certificate per team leader or one per application?

Tags: xcode, certificate, distribution, app-id

I'm confused by the dev and dist cert. I got one app in the store, but I named my certs after my first app. Was this a mistake?

I'm ready to go on my second app. But XCode is selected the dist cert with the old app name on it. It built without error. Though I named it wrong, will it still work? XCode is automatically picking this cert for me.

Is this right? You need a new app ID for each app so you can 1) put in plist, 2) put in code signing section on Build tab of Target info, but you don't need a new dev and dist cert for each new app.

Therefore is this right too? For each app you develop, you only need your original dev and dist cert, but a new app ID for each app.

This is so obscure! I wish apple had done a better job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these issues are fixed in the current (as of 7/2011) new processes Apple has in place. The Provisioning Portal cleaned up this mess and now it's not too hard. Still step-laden, but 1000x better than it was before.